# using last sapply output as next input

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I would like to use sapply in a way that the most recent value output from sapply becomes the next input to sapply. In the example below, I create vector a=(1, NA, NA, NA), and want sapply to return the vector a=(1,1,2,2). Basically, for a[2:4], I want the output to be 2-1=2, 3-1=2, 4=2=2

```
a <- NA
a[1] <- 1
a[2:4] <- sapply(2:4, function(x) x- a[x-1])
```

If you run this, you see it returns a=(1,1,NA,NA), as it uses the existing a vector rather than the "live" one.

as a for loop, it works like this:

```
a <- NA
a[1] <- 1
for (ii in 2:4){
  a[ii] <- ii-a[ii-1]
}
```

The reason I want to use sapply is because my real function is complex, and it will run over large data set and I don't want to wait for a very long time.

thanks.

Comment: You are unlikely to achieve a significant speed increase from using `sapply` instead of a well-written `for`-loop. I don't understand `2-1=2, 3-1=2, 4=2=2`

Comment: `sapply` won't do this, and even if it could it wouldn't really be much faster than a well written, pre-allocated `for` loop. It's possible your problem could be vectorized, but it's impossible to know without seeing your "real" function. Otherwise, for calculations the depend strongly on the previous iteration, I would strongly recommend **Rcpp** for speed gains.

Comment: @ docendo I'm sorry, that was a typo. should be 2-1=2, 3-1=2, 4-2=2. I realise that isn't so clear. The loop shown covers it though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `Reduce` for this

```
Reduce(f=function(lhs,rhs) rhs-lhs,x=1:4,accumulate=TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 2 2
```

Note that this will be slow if you run it on large data.

Then it is better to pre-allocate a vector and fill it via a `for` loop (as @joran suggested).